# what will be answers to the below questions , which options will not read the date in given format?

Tags: c

Which of the following three C code snippets WILL NOT read a date as three integers as follows:as int day, month, year;

```
a. printf("Enter date: "); scanf("%d/%2d/%2d", day, month, year);
b. printf("Enter date: "); gets( day); gets( month); gets( year);
c. printf("Enter date: ");scanf("%d", day); scanf("%d", month); scanf("%d", year);
```

Comment: None of them will work - see if you can work out why.

Answer (score 2):

If `day`, `month` and `year` are not pointers to `int`, then non of them will work. Otherwise 
Option `b` will not read date as integer.  `gets` **was used earlier** to read strings (it has been now omitted from the C standard).